Trying to build an app file using SQLite3 but it is unable to open database file. Any suggestions?
I am trying to build an app with SQLite that connects to a database, but I cannot get it to open said database. Is there anything I can put in my code so that it will open?
The directory works but the file will not connect to it. I have attached the dependencies and functions for reference:
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import sqlite3
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///Resources/hawaii.sqlite'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

Any help with accessing the database would be great!
I tried running the following code to see if my database would open:
def connect_to_database():
    db_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'sqlite:///Resources/hawaii.sqlite')
    
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db_path)
        print("Database opened successfully")
        return conn
    except sqlite3.Error as e:
        print(f"Error opening database: {e}")

connection = connect_to_database()

And I got the following message:

Error opening database: unable to open database file


db_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'sqlite:///Resources/hawaii.sqlite')

Here you are trying to concatenate a URI-like path with a filesystem path, achieving in db_path something like this:

/path/to/your/app/sqlite:///Resources/hawaii.sqlite'

Which is surely not a valid/existing path. sqlite3.connect expects first argument to be a regular filepath, so you should try:
conn = sqlite3.connect('Resources/hawaii.sqlite')

sqlite:// URI path is specific to SQLAlchemy and is probably used to detect desired SQL engine based on the URI format.
